# understanding resolving power in QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, measurements, eigenvalue, density-operator, observables

Consider the definition of *resolving power* of two states in quantum mechanics as being the absolute value of the difference between the probabilities of two states following the measurement averaged over the measurement results. Assume we upon measurement we obtain one of the basis states, would the resolving power of the following example be correct:

Given 
$$\rho = \frac{1}{2}|n \rangle \langle n| + \frac{1}{2}|m \rangle \langle m |$$ after measurement we have either $\rho_{after} = |n \rangle \langle n |$ or $\rho_{after} = |m \rangle \langle m|$, hence for the first possible result we have the sum $|1/2 - 1| + |1/2 - 0|  = 1$ and for the second we have $|1/2 -
 0| + |1/2 - 1| =1$, hence the average is $((|1/2 - 1| + |1/2 - 0|) + (|1/2 -
 0| + |1/2 - 1|))/2 = 1$. Hence the resolving power is $1$.

**Questions:**
Is this the correct understanding of resolvent power? Also, why when we consider a measurement of some observable, if two states have the same eigenvalue for the observable then the resolving power of these two states should be zero. Lastly, for pairs of states that have the same separation between their respective eigenvalues, how do you show that the resolving power is the same as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### In essence

**For a perfectly ideal, *strong*<sup>1</sup>  measurement, yes** - the resolving power of the above state is $1$. This ideal case can be referred to as a 'von Neumann measurement'

Otherwise, **a measurement can never be ideal** - there's going to be a finite probability that the measurement device will tell you that it has measured one outcome, when in fact, the state of the system has actually collapsed into a different outcome and so resolving power doesn't just depend on the state, but also on the measurement device, in which case, things aren't that simple...

For a more detailed/mathematical explanation (with examples), see below:

### Preamble: Measurement Pointers

However, in the real world, measurements aren't perfectly ideal. One simple way to model this is by saying that the measurement is in fact made by a 'pointer'. This pointer has a finite width and is assumed to be itself measured by an ideal, strong measurement<sup>2</sup>

So, in the ideal, strong measurement case, this pointer is considered to be a Dirac delta and in the non-ideal case, is assumed to have a Gaussian probability distribution<sup>3</sup>

To make a measurement of the observable $\hat{M}$, where the momentum operator of the pointer is $\hat{P}$. To use the pointer to measure $\hat{M}$, turn on a coupling $\lambda$ to create an addition to the Hamiltonian $\lambda \hat{M}\otimes\hat{P}$ and further assuming that the interaction occurs over a short enough time<sup>4</sup> for the Hamiltonians of the free pointer and uncoupled system to be neglected gives $H\simeq\lambda\hat{M}\otimes\hat{P}$.

Using the Schrödinger equation, denoting the wavefunction of the pointer in position space as $|\psi\left( x\right)\rangle$ and decomposing $\hat{M}$ into its eigenvalues $M_a$ and corresponding eigenvectors $|a\rangle$ gives the time evolution of the above as $$\hat{U}\left(t\right) = \sum_a \exp\left[-\frac{i}{\hbar}\lambda tM_a\hat{P}\right]|a\rangle\langle a|.$$

Taylor expanding (or any other suitable method) then gives $$\hat{U}\left(t\right)|\Psi\rangle = \hat{U}\left(t\right)\sum_a c_a |a\rangle|\psi\left( x\right)\rangle = \sum_a c_a |a\rangle |\psi\left(x - \lambda tM_a\right)\rangle.$$

At this point, it is hopefully clear that approximating the initial wavefunction of the pointer as a Dirac delta gives a weighted distribution of Dirac deltas at positions $\lambda tM_a$ and we get an ideal strong measurement.

### What's that got to do with resolving power?

As in the question, let's keep things simple and look at a spin-half system initially with the wavefunction $|\phi\rangle = \alpha|\uparrow\rangle + \beta|\downarrow\rangle$, with the initial wavefunction of the pointer as $$|\psi\left(t = 0\right)\rangle = \int dx\left(\left(\Delta x\right)^2 2\pi\right)^{-\frac{1}{4}}\exp\left[-\frac{x^2}{4\left(\Delta x\right)^2}\right]|x\rangle.$$

Evolving this state as above gives $$|\Psi\left(t\right)\rangle = \int dx\left(\left(\Delta x\right)^2 2\pi\right)^{-\frac{1}{4}}\left(\alpha|\uparrow\rangle\exp\left[-\frac{\left(x - \lambda t\right)^2}{4\left(\Delta x\right)^2}\right] + \beta|\downarrow\rangle\exp\left[-\frac{\left(x + \lambda t\right)^2}{4\left(\Delta x\right)^2}\right]\right)|x\rangle ,$$

or in figure form:[image: The probability distribution of the position of a von Neumann pointer after a strong interaction of a spin-$\frac{1}{2}$ particle originally in the state (a) $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|\uparrow\rangle + |\downarrow\rangle\right)$ and (b) $\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{3}|\uparrow\rangle + |\downarrow\rangle\right)$. with the values $\Delta x = \frac{1}{10}$ and $\lambda t = 1$]Figure 1: The probability distribution of the position of a von Neumann pointer after a strong interaction of a spin-$\frac{1}{2}$ particle originally in the state (a) $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|\uparrow\rangle + |\downarrow\rangle\right)$ and (b) $\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{3}|\uparrow\rangle + |\downarrow\rangle\right)$. with the values $\Delta x = \frac{1}{10}$ and $\lambda t = 1$

Or... [image: The probability distribution of the position of a von Neumann pointer after a weakened interaction of a spin-$\frac{1}{2}$ particle originally in the state (a) $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|\uparrow\rangle + |\downarrow\rangle\right)$ and (b) $\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{3}|\uparrow\rangle + |\downarrow\rangle\right)$, with the values $\Delta x = 10$ and $\lambda t = 1$]Figure 2: The probability distribution of the position of a von Neumann pointer after a weakened interaction of a spin-$\frac{1}{2}$ particle originally in the state (a) $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|\uparrow\rangle + |\downarrow\rangle\right)$ and (b) $\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{3}|\uparrow\rangle + |\downarrow\rangle\right)$, with the values $\Delta x = 10$ and $\lambda t = 1$

The difference between these two figures shows a different resolving power, defined (as per the question) as the "absolute value of the difference between the probabilities of two states following the measurement averaged over the measurement results"

For the ideal case of the measurement outcomes being Dirac deltas, we have: when $|\downarrow\rangle$ is measured - the state is in $|\downarrow\rangle$ with probability $1$ and when $|\uparrow\rangle$ is measured, the state is now in $|\uparrow\rangle$ with probability $1$. So, the absolute value of the difference between the probability of the state being $|\downarrow\rangle$ and $|\uparrow\rangle$ *after* the measurement is $1$, regardless of the measurement outcome (this is the same for both case a) and b) ), giving a resolving power of $1$, as stated in the question.

Otherwise, we have:

- The measurement result is $x$ (the position of the pointer)
- The difference between the probabilities at a point $x$ is $$\mathbb{P}_{\downarrow}\left( x\right) - \mathbb{P}_{\uparrow}\left( x\right) = \frac{1}{\left(\Delta x\right)\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(\left|\beta\right|^2\exp\left[-\frac{\left(x + \lambda t\right)^2}{2\left(\Delta x\right)^2}\right] - \left|\alpha\right|^2\exp\left[-\frac{\left(x - \lambda t\right)^2}{2\left(\Delta x\right)^2}\right]\right)$$

Evaluating the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left|\mathbb{P}_{\downarrow}\left( x\right) - \mathbb{P}_{\uparrow}\left( x\right)\right|dx$ numerically gives (the approximate value of the resolving power for figure number):

- 1. a) $1$
- 1. b) $1$
- 2. a) $0.08$
- 2. b) $0.5$

## A More Mathematical Definition, using pointers

And so, using measurement pointers, for an interaction occuring over a short enough time<sup>4</sup>, the **Resolving Power can be defined as**: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left|\mathbb{P}_0\left( x\right) - \mathbb{P}_1\left( x\right)\right|dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(\Delta x\right)\sqrt{2\pi}}\left|\left|\beta\right|^2\exp\left[-\frac{\left(x - M_1\lambda t\right)^2}{2\left(\Delta x\right)^2}\right] - \left|\alpha\right|^2\exp\left[-\frac{\left(x - M_0\lambda t\right)^2}{2\left(\Delta x\right)^2}\right]\right|dx$$

For a system initially in the state $\alpha|0\rangle + \beta|1\rangle$, measured using the measurement operator $\hat{M} = M_0|0\rangle\langle 0| + M_1|1\rangle\langle 1|$ with a pointer with standard deviation $\Delta x$, with interaction strength $\lambda$

### Finally

It's worth noting that the book you used to define resolving power only defined it for $\alpha = \beta$, so making that assumption:

Setting $M_0 = M_1$ gives a resolving power of $0$, as expected.

Before performing the measurement, ensuring that the pointer is centred halfway between $M_0$ and $M_1$ will give the same probability distribution (except shifted by that value) for every state with the same difference between $M_0$ and $M_1$, assuming everything else stays the same. As the integral is from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, this has no effect on the resolution power and so, the resolution power is the same for every state with the same separation between eigenvalues.

---

<sup>1</sup>The ideas used in this answer (especially the bit about pointers) are often also used in what's known as weak measurements. An ideal weak measurement is the opposite of an ideal strong measurement, hence the need to constantly refer to strong measurements

<sup>2</sup>Using another pointing device to measure the previous pointing device can lead to what's known as the von Neumann measurement chain - here (to avoid the measurement problem) the state is assumed to decohere at some point during the observation, effectively causing an ideal, strong measurement to take place

<sup>3</sup>Aside: in this case, the delta function is taken to be the limit of the standard deviation of the Gaussian tending to $0$

<sup>4</sup>It turns out that this assumption isn't actually necessary, but it simplifies everything a bit